# Generate unique key from List of int in Java

Tags: java, list, key

I have many (immutable) lists of `Integer` values.

A few of them are containing the exact same values. So in order to save memory I'd like to find those.
For that reason I'm using a `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>`

A working approach is to simply concatenate the values to one large `String` and use it as a key in the `HashMap`.

This approach works reliably, but it is very slow and consumes a lot of memory.

My `Integer` values are in between 1 and 100,000,000. The lists are containing in between 1 and 1000 `Integer` values.

There could be up to 100,000,000 lists.

I need to be sure that there are no collisions.

Comment: Let's assume that you have two lists, one which is `1 -> 2 -> 3` and other which is `2 -> 1 -> 3`.  Both contain the same numbers, but if I concatenate each to a `String` in order, I don't end up with the same thing.  How are you concatenating the various lists, and is there any order?

Comment: In my opinion it takes much more effort to check for equality than to have a few duplicates of Lists.

Comment: why not to use `hashCode` as a map key?

Comment: @rzysia: Because hashCodes are not collision safe.

Comment: @flown the "few" duplicates in my current implementation make up about 30GB of memory

Comment: It is not possible to compute a **unique** short key (say, an `int` or a `long`) for an arbitrary list of integers because of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). If this were possible, you'd have a fantastic compression algorithm - you could compress any amount of data into a small, fixed-length code... which is obviously impossible.

Comment: Well, unique is such a harsh word. But I mean it is possible to generate keys where the probability of collision is as likely as a meteor falling on your head. But what is the best strategy to do so? From what I see now probably the best is to generate a String and then use some SHA algorithm

Answer (score 2):

- transform the list into a `BigInteger`
- `Arrays.hashCode()` or `List.hashCode()`, as appropriate.
- A CRC32
- An SHA256, 512, ...

Comment: using the default .hashCode() method is not collision safe. Do you have a reccomendatio how to implement it collision safe?

Comment: *No* `hashCode()` method is collision-safe. You're never going to get it collision-safe with that much data and that much range. You'll have to accept that this is a hashcode that requires a further test on equality. It will still save you masses of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some hash function for your collection.
I think this answer may help you - https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/is-there-a-hash-function-for-a-collection-i-e-multi-set-of-integers-that-has

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Set.  Here is an example using Java8.  It takes in two lists and creates a separate Set which contains just the duplicate entries from list1 and list2:

```
    Integer[] a = {1,2,2,3,1};
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(a);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(a);

    Set<Integer> duplicates = list1.stream().filter(entry -> list2.contains(entry)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```